# How to retrieve the latest event with a given field value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I index events similar to the ones below:

```
{
  "time": "2015-10-01",
  "kind": "A"
},
{
  "time": "2015-10-02",
  "kind": "B"
},
{
  "time": "2015-10-15",
  "kind": "A"
},
{
  "time": "2015-10-16",
  "kind": "B"
}
```

In other words, these are timed events of several kinds (`A` and `B` in the example above). It is guaranteed that there cannot be two or more events of the same `kind` with the same `time`.

**I am looking for a query which would retrieve the latest (`time` closest to "now") events for each kind.** For the example above these would be the lat two ones.

Up to now, I was forcing the `_id` to have the value of `kind`, which automatically kept a set of unique events (the events are indexed with time, so the one with the date of `2015-10-16` is guaranteed to be indexed after the one from an earlier `2015-10-02`). This of course does not keep the history of events, something I am now interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_kind": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "kind",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "time"
          }
        },
        "1st": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{"time":"desc"}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I did not know you could nest `aggs`.